# How to add zoom option for wordcloud in Shiny (with reproducible example)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, word-cloud

Could you please help me to add zooming option for wordcloud

Please find reproducible example @
 ´http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/word-cloud.html´

I tried to incorporate rbokeh and plotly but couldnt find wordcloud equivalent render function
Additionally, I found ECharts from github @
 ´https://github.com/XD-DENG/ECharts2Shiny/tree/8ac690a8039abc2334ec06f394ba97498b518e81´

But incorporating this ECharts are also not convenient for really zoom.

Thanks in advance,
Abi

Comment: Yes, PCA can result in the loss of *something* if you use it for dimensionality reduction. You usually do this to get rid of noise, in which case I would argue it is not *information* that was lost. Anyway, please improve your question to show what you actually do. If it is about how to use PCA correctly, consider asking at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalisation is required only if the predictors are not meant to be comparable on the original scaling. There's no rule that says you must normalize.

PCA is a statistical method that gives you a new linear transformation. By itself, it loses nothing. All it does is to give you new principal components.

You lose information only if you choose a subset of those principal components.

Answer (score 0):

Usually PCA includes centering the data as a Pre Process Step.

PCA only arranges the data in its own Axis (Eigne Vectors) System.
If you use all axis you lose no information.

Yet, usually we want to apply [Dimensionality Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction), intuitively, having less coordinates for the data.
This process means projecting the data into Sub Space which is spanned by only some of the Eigen Vectors of the data.
If one chose wisely the number of vectors one might end up with a significant reduction in the number of dimensions of the data with negligible loss of data / information.
The way to do so is by choosing Eigen Vectors which their Eigen Values sum to most of the data power.

Answer (score 0):

PCA itself is *invertible*, so lossless.

But:

1. It is common to drop some components, which will cause a loss of information.
2. Numerical issues may cause a loss in precision.